# What does it mean to cut a surface along some curve?

Tags: general-topology, surfaces

Intuitively, I understand what it means to take a surface and cut it along a curve. However, I don't feel that I have a comfy, rigorous definition of what this actually means. The book *A Primer on Mapping Class Groups* by Farb and Margalit use the following definition:

> Given a simple closed curve $\alpha$ in a surface $S$, the surface obtained by *cutting* $S$ along $\alpha$ is a compact surface $S_{\alpha}$ equipped with a homeomorphism $h$ between two of its boundary components so that
>
> 1. the quotient $S_{\alpha}/(x\sim h(x))$ is homeomorphic to $S$, and
> 2. the image of these distinguished boundary components under this quotient map is $\alpha$.

Something about this definition feels lacking to me. **Are there other equivalent definitions out there, or should I learn to work with this definition better?**

Comment: @MonstrousMoonshiner I want to have a definition where actions on $S$ yield actions on $S_{\alpha}$, e.g. one where proving that $f(S_{\alpha}) = S_{f(\alpha)}$ feels natural. Moishe Cohen's second definition feels much better.

Comment: Then you should edit your question. Definition 1 works equivariantly as long as you work with diffeomorphisms, which is harmless. The point is that given two Riemannian metrics on $S$, the two completions of $S-C$ are naturally hopmeomorpic, when $C$ is a compact in $S$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, of course:

1. Suppose that $\alpha$ is a smooth simple loop on $S$; equip $S$ with a complete Riemannian metric $g$. Then $S- \alpha$ has an incomplete Riemannian metric obtained by the restriction of $g$. Take $S'$ to be the completion of 
   $(S- \alpha,g)$. This is your surface with boundary obtained by splitting of $S$ along $\alpha$.
2. Instead of using Riemannian geometry one can use PL topology. Triangulate $S$ so that $\alpha$ is a subcomplex. Let $N(\alpha)$ be the (closed) regular neighborhood of $\alpha$ in $S$. Then $S'$ is the complement $S- int(N(\alpha))$.
3. You can combine 1 and 2 by assuming that $\alpha$ is smooth and remove from $S$ an open tubular neighborhood ${N}^\circ(\alpha)$ of $\alpha$.

Comment: Wait, wouldn't the completion of $(S-\alpha, g)$ just be $S$ again?

Comment: I would think you ought to modify the metric $g$ so that the two disconnected pieces are no longer “close together”.

Comment: @MonstrousMoonshiner: No, no need to modify, they are no close together since I am using the Riemannian distance function induced by the restricted Riemannian metric, in order to define the completion.

Comment: But even in the restricted Riemmannian metric, you can find points on opposite sides of $\alpha$ that are arbitrarily close together

Comment: @MonstrousMoonshiner: Nope: The distance in $S-\alpha$ between $x, y$ is the infimum of length of paths connecting $x$ to $y$ and contained in  $S-\alpha$. If $x, y$ are locally separated by $\alpha$, such a path cannot be short (even if the surface is connected).

Comment: Ah, I see. I was thinking of the restriction of the original distance function to $S - \alpha$, not the distance function induced by the restriction of $g$ to $S-\alpha$.

Comment: So if the surface is no longer connected, would points in opposite components be infinitely far apart?

Comment: @MonstrousMoonshiner: Right.